# jinja2 iterate an array of strings

Tags: jinja2

I'm using jinja2 and python.

Everything works but a table printed based on a string of arrays, this is the template

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th> {{table.title}}</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    {% for value in table.values %}
          <td> {{ value }} </td>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
</table>
```

Table is defined in data in the pyton:

```
data['table'] = {
    'title': 'Title',
     'values': ['test','test2']
}
templateVars = data.copy()
templateEnv = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(f'{package_directory}/assets/templates/'))
outputText = template.render(templateVars)
```

When executing I get an error:

```
{% for value in table.values %}
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

I can't find the error, because I created a list, and it should be iterable. I copied the same code to python and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, it was I was using "values" as key and it's a reserved word, changing it for table_rows it works